# Using activeClassName attribute on sub component - React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I currently have a sidebar with several links. I want to make it so that when the user navigates to a certain page, the respective sidebar item is selected. I'm using React Router and am using the `NavLink` component. Here is my code:

```js
<Router>
    <div className="bg-2 h-full fixed w-60 border-r default-border">
        <Logo fill="#ffff" height="25px" width="" className="m-7 mt-8 mb-8" />
        <NavLink to="/dashboard"><NavItem icon={faHome} text="Home"/></NavLink>
        <div className="mt-8">
            <NavLink to="/payments"><NavItem icon={faReceipt} text="Payments" /></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/releases"><NavItem icon={faShoppingCart} text="Releases" /></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/keys"><NavItem icon={faKey} text="Keys" /></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/customers"><NavItem icon={faUserAlt} text="Customers" /></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/packages"><NavItem icon={faBoxOpen} text="Packages" /></NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-8">
           <NavLink to="/developers"><NavItem icon={faCode} text="Developers" /></NavLink>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <NavLink to="/apikeys"><SubItem text="API Keys" /></NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/logs"><SubItem text="Logs" /></NavLink>
            </div>
            <NavLink to="/settings"><NavItem icon={faCog} text="Settings" /></NavLink>
        </div>
    </div>

    <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Home/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/payments">
            <Payments/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/releases">
            <Releases/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/keys">
            <Keys/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/customers">
            <Customers/>
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

As you can see, inside of the `NavLink`, I have my own component `NavItem`. The `NavItem` code is as follows:

```js
const NavItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="group ml-7 cursor-pointer flex flex-row my-1.5 items-center text-gray-400">
            <div className="text-center w-5">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} className="group-hover:text-gray-300 transition text-sm" />
            </div>
            <span className="font-medium ml-4 group-hover:text-gray-300 transition text-sm">{props.text}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My issue is that when I try to use the [activeClassName](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string) attribute from React Router, it does not apply to the `NavItem` component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Active appears to only apply to NavLink. I would just use specificity in the CSS selectors to go to the child, NavItem.

Comment: Not that it adds a lot to your question but might help clean your code a little. Routes can have a component attribute and just takes the component name:
`<Route path="/home" component={Home} />`

Comment: Appreciate that @MatthewDAuld

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating my own state tracking and passing state to `NavItem` component.